# I can't distinguish words while listening to someone

Tags: spoken-english, listening

I can't know that how can I explain. When listening to English speaking people I cannot understand some words. It's like they roll in their mouths. There are times when I cannot understand a sentence because of a word. How can I overcome? Is there a way that are you know?

(I hope I did use true that "distinguish" word. )

Comment: Practice. And more practice, then, more practice.

Comment: After studying German for many years, I went to Germany and found that everything that was said to me sounded like one giant word (and considering German is a language with giant words I wasn't sure if they were sentences or not).  After listening to everyone talk for a few weeks the words became clearer -- like magic.  Keep listening.  Give it time.

Comment: I consided your suggestions. Actually, I understand the speeches, but I can't understand a few words in the sentence, so that the sentence had lost meaning. Thanks again. I'll apply.

Comment: If I understand you...it sounds more like you don't understand one word (mishearing, never heard it before, etc.), and that means you can't understand the whole sentence? Rather than not being able to understand the whole sentence because of accent or talking quickly?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes i don't understand because accent. But mostly i dont understand to quickly talk. It's like rolling words in their mouths.

Comment: When someone talks too fast for me, in English or another language, and I have heard something that seems wrong, I repeat what I heard more slowly. This lets the person know about both the specific confusion and the more general point, how slowly I want him to talk.

Comment: It takes time and you have to work your way up the ladder of complexity. Judging by your question, you are probably an intermediate learner.You have to study in stages. I suggest   you find a well-structured course and concentrate on your grammar.

Comment: at least one *possibility* is you don't know the word, or not thoroughly enough. That would be expected for an intermediate learner, and could be improved by more reading.  It's difficult to hear a word properly when it's very existence and meaning are also unfamiliar.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Are you know a site for improving understand(word, shortened verbs, etc.) skills?